# How ARM Linux switch into Thumb2 Mode during decompression the kernel in head.S

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I have a problem when reading the linux kernel base on the release 4.15 and later from mainline. In the arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S, I have read something like this.

```
133: #ifndef CONFIG_THUMB2_KERNEL
134:    mov r0, r0
135: #else
136:    AR_CLASS(   sub pc, pc, #3  )   @ A/R: switch to Thumb2 mode
137:    M_CLASS(    nop.w           )   @ M: already in Thumb2 mode
138:    .thumb
139: #endif
```

The Line 136 says that in Thumb2, it can switch cpu to Thumb-2 mode, by basiclly jump to the address which is 0x300 offset lower than the current PC address. And I have searched some other articles, some of them use  'adr' or 'xadr' to switch to Thumb2 mode.

My question is : Why the CPU can switch to Thumb2 mode by this way?  What's the different from using 'bx'?

Comment: what way were you thinking instead?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is : Why the CPU can switch to Thumb2 mode by this way? What's the different from using 'bx'?

Look at the code and the comments...

```
136:    AR_CLASS(   sub pc, pc, #3  )   @ A/R: switch to Thumb2 mode
137:    M_CLASS(    nop.w           )   @ M: already in Thumb2 mode
138:    .thumb
```

First, on ARMs with Thumb support, setting the `PC` to an odd address switches to thumb mode.  I guess you knew that?  Second the ARM PC is always 8 bytes ahead of the currently executing instructions.  So `sub pc, pc, #3` is like go to next instruction in *thumb2* mode.

But what if the CPU is already in thumb2 mode (from boot like a cortex-M)?  `BX` doesn't make sense on a CPU that only has thumb mode.  The `AR_CLASS` macro defines as nothing for the Cortex-M CPUs.  The [`M_CLASS`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/asm/unified.h#L28) defines as nothing for Cortex-A CPUs.

I have seen code (in U-Boot I believe) that had instructions that were intended to execute in both modes.  In *thumb* mode, the opcodes were a no-op and in ARM mode the did a branch.  The specific opcode have different meanings in the mode but identical binary numbers.

**why** is always a tough question to answer.  It maybe that the ARM `sub` opcode is harmless in Thumb2.  Also, some older CPUs may not support `BX`.

Comment: Why - fewer instructions, no registers corrupted would be my guess... Looks odd though.

Comment: `bx` would not alter registers (except cpsr which is altered by desire; `blx` would alter the `lr` but this is not the OPs suggestion).  Also, there are not *fewer* instructions.  There is a `nop` for M_CLASS and the single `sub` for ARM.  This is as dense as the single `bx` instruction.